# I want "(int)null" to return me 0

Tags: c#, .net, casting

How can i get 0 as integer value from `(int)null`.

**EDIT 1:** I want to create a function that will return me default values for null representation in their respective datatypes.

**EDIT 2:**
How can i work in this **scenario** for using **default**.

(int)Value

Where **Value can be null or any integer** value. I dont know datatype of value at run time.
But i will assure that Value should either contain null or Integer value only.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the Nullable structure

```
int value = new Nullable<int>().GetValueOrDefault();
```

You can also use the `default` keyword

```
int value = default(int);
```

Following 2nd edit:

You need a function that receive any type of parameter, so object will be used. Your function is similar to the `Field<T>` extension method on a `DataRow`

```
public static T GetValue<T>(object value)
{
    if (value == null || value == DBNull.Value)
        return default(T);
    else
        return (T)value;
}
```

Using that function, if you want an int (and you expect value to be an int) you call it like:

```
int result = GetValue<int>(dataRow["Somefield"]);
```

Comment: I agree.  No need to reinvent the wheel - use the build it language feature - nullable types.

Comment: @Pierre-Alain Vigeant: Need more explanation on "new Nullable<int>().GetValueOrDefault();" about what and how it works. I gets bit confused using <Field> dont know about this kind of syntax code

Comment: @ShantanuGupta A nullable type like `int?` provides a method called GetValueOrDefault(). This method returns the value if it is not null or the default value of the type (0 for an int) if the value is null.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta GetField<T> the T is a generic type. You can read about generics at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Pierre-Alain Vigeant: very nice answer given. Thx

Comment: Also just for the sake of completeness, default(int?) would return null as would any Nullable type as opposed to the default value of the wrapped type. So be aware that although default(int) resolves to 0 default(int?) intuitively resolves down to just null. As for whether (int?)null or default(int?) is preferable in code I'm not sure but it would be easy to do a quick test to see the resulting IL and do a quick performance test.

Answer (score 43):

You can use the [`default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) keyword to get the default value of any data type:

```
int x = default(int);        //  == 0
string y = default(string);  //  == null
// etc.
```

This works with generic parameters as well:

```
Bar<T> Foo<T>() {
    return new Bar<T>(default(T));
}
```

---

In case you have a variable of type `object` that may contain `null` or a value  of type `int`, you can use [nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) and the [?? operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to convert it safely to an integer:

```
int a = 42;
object z = a;
int b = (int?)z ?? 0;        //  == 42
int c = (int?)null ?? 0;     //  == 0
```

Comment: I miss c++ so much!

Answer (score 3):

Use **null-coalescing operator** or **`??`**

Example:

```
int? a = null;
return a ?? 0; //this will return 0
```

It's a new feature in C#. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise, it returns the right-hand operand.

Answer (score 2):

A generic method that returns a cast instance of an object or the default value could be implemented as follows:

```
static T Cast<T>(object value) {
    if (value is T)
        return (T)value;
    else
        return default(T);
}
```

This way, using a valid value will yield the value itself:

```
int value = Cast<int>(4); //value = 4
```

and a null value will get the default:

```
int value = Cast<int>(null); //value = 0
```

Notice that since the method takes object as an argument, this will cause boxing when used with struct objects (like int).

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a `null` to an int, as an int is a value type. You *can* cast it to an `int?` though.

What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: @thecoop: I am trying to make a general function for returning me a default values for all the datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

A method of a generic class that returns nothing works:

```
 Class GetNull(Of T)
      Public Shared Function Value() As T
           Return Nothing
      End Function
 End Class



 Debug.Print(GetNull(Of Integer).Value())
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post for a mostly complete method for writing an extension to do just this. My scenario is pulling data from a NameValueCollection.

http://hunterconcepts.com/blog/Extensions_HttpRequestFormQueryString/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a return type of `Nullable(Of Integer)`.