# How to override default(int?) to obtain NULL instead 0

Tags: c#, null

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096619/i-want-intnull-to-return-me-0) the method:

```
public static T GetValue<T>(object value)
{
    if (value == null || value == DBNull.Value)
        return default(T);
    else
        return (T)value;
}
```

How to rewrite it to obtain null if "value" is NULL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to rewrite it. You just need to call it as:

```
GetValue<int?>(value);
```

Answer (score 5):

`int` is a **value type** not a reference type - it cannot have a value of `null`.

Consider using `int?` instead if your INT column in the database is nullable.

Answer (score 5):

> How to rewrite it to obtain null if "value" is NULL?

You can’t – `int` cannot be `null`. You can, however, use `Nullable<int>` instead. But this only works for value types. For instance, it *won’t* work any more for `T == string`. In order to accomplish this you will need to write two distinct functions, one for nullable value types and one for reference types.

```
public T? GetValue<T>(object value) where T : struct
{
    if (value == null || value == DBNull.Value)
        return null;
    else
        return (T?)value;
}
```

Or, terser:

```
public T? GetValue<T>(object value) where T : struct
{
    return (value == null value == DBNull.Value) ? null : (T?)value;
}
```

(In all cases, `T?` is a shortcut for `Nullable<T>`.)

Comment: -1 - The code above won't work for reference types - you can't have `Nullable<string>`. It will be enough to call the original method using `int?` as `T`.

Comment: @Konrad - but this limits the usage of this general function to value types only - have you seen a database without strings? ;-)

Comment: @Jakub Don’t ask me – I’d just use an existing database abstraction layer and be done with it.

Comment: @Konrad - sorry, I don't get your answer at all - you've suggested that all domain objects that represent tables (that's where this code is probably used - to populate objects from db reader) can only use nullable value types. That's a BIG limitation and I would guess not a desirable one.

Comment: @Jakub No. I’m suggesting either using two distinct functions for incompatible type classes (value types and reference types) or using @degorolls’s approach (i.e. not changing the function).

Answer (score 0):

In C#, an int is a value type and therefore cannot be null as Jakub said. However, you can define a variable :

```
int? thisValue;
```

This can be set to null.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this:

```
public T GetValue<T>(object value){
    if (value == null)
        return null;
    else if (value == DBNull.Value)
        return default(T);
    else
        return (T)value;
}
```